# React native doesn't see new table in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I'm using a sqlite database linked to my react-native app.

I've already done some queries in my app that work fine, so the query method is good.

Now, I've add new table to the database by adding a csv file in it (as I've already done before).

But when I make a call on the new table, the console tells me that there is 'no such table'.
If I put the sql query in my DB manager, the call do works.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I did find the solution.

It is very simple, just create a new emulator and rerun your app. It seems that Android Studio works on a 'copy' of the project so it does not see the modification in the database.